AWS RDS MariaDB slow logs empty rows
I enabled the slow query logging on my AWS mariadb RDS as described here. And set up the publishing to Cloudwatch logs.
Parameter group family:
mariadb10.11
My parameters:
log_output = FILE
log_slow_query_time = 0.2
log_slow_query  = 1

This works, as my slow querys are logged to Cloudwatch
2024-08-21T11:13:15.000Z
# Time: 240821 11:13:15# User@Host: user[user] @ [1.2.3.4]
# Thread_id: 851891  Schema: dpd  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 0.301404  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 59
use db_name;
SET timestamp=1724932120;
SELECT SLEEP(0.3)
LIMIT 0, 200;

But in addition to that there are also many log rows, that usually come after that.
2024-08-21T11:13:15.000Z
Time Id Command Argument

2024-08-21T11:13:15.000Z
Time Id Command Argument

2024-08-21T11:13:15.000Z
Time Id Command Argument

This makes it harder to find the actual slow query. How can this be disabled?
I have tried:
log_slow_min_examined_row_limit = 1

But with this parameter still these rows appear

The answer might be you can't, this is just how the databases are set up to write occasional log headers. I'm guessing you have multi-AZ redundancy and that's triggering the duplicate headers?

The "Time Id Command Argument" occurs on flush [slow] logs. Given the precise 15 minute increment this appears to be a scripted event. If its always the same time, enable the general log around this interval and look what was executed. 3 flushes at the same time seems excessive.

I am not using multi-AZ database. @Rup

Appears, that the flushes are every 5 minutes, so new log lines appear every 5 min. In slowquery.log there are these lines after slow query
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld, Version: 10.11.8-MariaDB-log (managed by https://aws.amazon.com/rds/). started with: Tcp port: 3306 Unix socket: /tmp/mysql.sock Time Id Command Argument 
So this means CW does not have the timestamp, thus takes the same time as slow query was logged. And these are logged every 5 minutes until the slow log file rotates. Rotation is done every hour once. But still can it not be turned off?

That's a question for MariaDB really, if they support turning off writing the log flush headers when there's nothing to flush. And then AWS to work out how to configure that. I might ask AWS directly in the first instance anyway.

Headers are written post flush in anticipation of new events. At this point its unknown how many slow queries will need to be logged. Do ask AWS.

What is the value of long_query_time?

@RickJames
In mariadb10.11 parameter group there is no such key as long_query_time, but log_slow_query_time is 0.2

One is the alias of the other.  0.2 is good.
